# Using php flow control when accessing methods and classes

Tags: php, class, methods, control-flow

I am currently using a class to control access to certain files in my site. The class works fine. However, i've recently been informed that I need to create a much more fine-grained system for one particular section of the site. My first inclination was to use nested if-else-if to set a couple of variables.

```
$admin = new Admin();

if( $admin->user_access('can_view_g2')) {
    $groupNum = $group2;
    $adminGroup = true;
    } else {

if( $admin->user_access('can_view_g3')) {
    $groupNum = $group3;
    $adminGroup = false;
    } else {

if( $admin->user_access('can_view_g4')) {
    $groupNum = $group4;
    $adminGroup = true;
    } else {

. . .
```

Now I would like to eliminate a few lines of code and create a cleaner flow-control statement. I'd like to use a switch statement to handle this, but i'm not sure it is possible since I am accessing the methods and properties of a class.

```
switch ($admin->user_access($permission)) {

    case 'can_view_g2':
        $groupNum = $group2;
        $adminGroup = true;

    break;

    case 'can_view_g3':
        $groupNum = $group3;
        $adminGroup = true;;

    break;

    case 'can_view_g4':
        $groupNum = $group4;
        $adminGroup = true;

    . . .
```

What I have above is not working. Does anyone know of a way to do this or at least a more efficient flow control method to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your just trying to turn the block of if/else into a switch/case:

```
switch (true) {
    case $admin->user_access('can_view_g2'):
        $groupNum = $group2;
        $adminGroup = true;
    break;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess this is visually cleaner, but efficiency wise, it's the same as the if/else statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user_access = $admin -> user_access($permission);
switch($user_acces) {
...
```

This because of the "cannot use return value ...." something error..

Comment: `$user_access` evaluates to a `true` or `false`

Comment: Ah, wait, I know see the differences Interstellar_Coder! Then my "solution" isn't going to work, my apologies!